# Jquery contains for lists

Tags: jquery, django

I am using Jquery to select an individual member of a list that contains a certain href link.

Here is my code so far:

```
<script type="text/javascript" 
 src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.4.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
    var page = jQuery(location).attr('href'); 
    if(page $= "home"){
        $("'li':contains('index')").addClass("active")};
    if(page $= "features"){
        $("'li':contains('features')").addClass("active")};
    if(page $= "people"){
        $("'li':contains('people')").addClass("active") };
    if(page $= "accounts"){
        $("'li':contains('accounts')").addClass("active")};
    if(page $= "blog"){
        $("'li':contains('blog')").addClass("active")};  
    if(page $= "faq"){
        $("'li':contains('faq')").addClass("active")};                      
});
</script>
```

The HTML code looks like this:

```
<ul id="navigation">
  <li><a href="/index" title="Home">Home</a></li>
  <li><a href="/features" title="Features">Features</a></li>
  <li><a href="/people" title="People">People</a></li>
  <li><a href="/accounts" title="account">accounts</a></li>
  <li><a href="/blog" title="Blog">Blog</a></li>
  <li><a href="/faq" title="FAQ">FAQ</a></li>
</ul>
```

I can't seem to get this to work?  Am I using the contain feature correctly?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[`:contains`](http://api.jquery.com/contains-selector/) searches the `innerText` of the element.  You want [`:has`](http://api.jquery.com/has-selector/), which will scan `innerHTML`.

Also, for the href attribute, you need to use the [attribute selector](http://api.jquery.com/category/selectors/attribute-selectors/): `[href="index"]`.

```
$("li:has(a[href*='index'])")
```

This will select the `<li>` that contains an `<a>` tag with an href containing `"index"`.

UPDATE:

```
if(page $= "home")
```

You can't actually do that.  If you want to see if a string ends with another, use a regex (or substring).

```
jQuery(location).attr('href');
```

Why use jQuery for this?  Just do `location.href`.  Better yet, use `location.pathname`.  Then, you can lose the `if` blocks, and simply do this:

```
var page = location.pathname;
$("li:has(a[href*='"+page+"'])").addClass("active");
```

(You may need to do `page.replace('home', 'index')`)

Comment: I did this.. I was able to debug and the page variable is storing the correct path, however I don't have an response.... in query you don't have to call any functions do you?

Comment: @ChristopherH: What does `console.log(location.pathname)` say?  What do you mean by "don't have to call any functions"?

Comment: I got it... the location.pathname has an end forward slash that my href didn't have.  Thanks.